# Mocha test passes with incorrect data

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I have the following test using Mocha, Supertest and Chai:

```
const app = require('../server')
const expect = require('chai').should()
const request = require('supertest')

describe('GET /webhook', function () {
  context('a verify request from Facebook with a correct token', function() {
    it('responds with 200 and displays the challenge query in the response body', function() {
      request(app)
        .get('/webhook?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=123456789&hub.verify_token=' + process.env.FB_VERIFY_TOKEN)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function (err, res) {
          console.log(res.text)
          res.should.have.property("text", "abc")
          done()
        })
    })
  })
})
```

As you can see, we're expecting the response to have a property 'text' with the content of 'abc'. However, when I run the tests it passes without any problems.

Here is a shortened version of the response:

```
ClientRequest{  
   res:IncomingMessage   {  
      headers:{  
         'x-powered-by':'Express',
         'content-type':'text/html; charset=utf-8',
         'content-length':'9',
         etag:'W/"9-JfnnlDI7RTiF9RgfG2JNCw"',
         date:'Mon, 27 Feb 2017 19:45:30 GMT',
         connection:'close'
      },
      rawHeaders:[  
         'X-Powered-By',
         'Express',
         'Content-Type',
         'text/html; charset=utf-8',
         'Content-Length',
         '9',
         'ETag',
         'W/"9-JfnnlDI7RTiF9RgfG2JNCw"',
         'Date',
         'Mon, 27 Feb 2017 19:45:30 GMT',
         'Connection',
         'close'
      ],
      upgrade:false,
      url:'',
      method:null,
      statusCode:200,
      statusMessage:'OK',
      req:[  
         Circular
      ],
      text:'123456789',
   }
}
```

I'm expecting the test to fail, as abc != 123456789, but unfortunately this isn't the case.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not sure on this, but it looks to me like `res.should.have.property('text', 'abc')` needs to be changed to `expect(res).to.have.property('text', 'abc');`  Note that you would also have to change `const expect = require('chai').should()` to `const expect = require('chai');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you have asynchronous operation, you need to tell to test runner to wait for async operation to be done. Using `mocha` you can either return a promise from test or you can use `done` callback or call it whatever you want.

In your case while you are calling `done` callback, you are not passing it to test callback, it should be:

```
it('should bla bla', function (done) {
  ...
  // call done()
})
```

Comment: Oh my word. I've clearly been up for far too long. Thank you for finding that!